# Why my function returns ZERO why it shouldn't in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

I have an R function called `Likelihood` that works well when `observations` in my code is `seq(1, 30)`. However, I can't understand why `observations = seq(1, 50)` it starts to give all **ZEROS**. I appreciate ideas regarding how to overcome this problem?

**Here is my R code:**

```
observations = seq(1, 60)  
n = length(observations)  
x_bar = mean(observations) 
SIGMA = 2            
SE = SIGMA / sqrt(n)       
x.min = x_bar - 4*SE
x.max = x_bar + 4*SE

Likelihood = function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = observations, SIGMA), prod) # Natural Log??
curve(Likelihood, from = x.min, to = x.max, col = 'red', lwd = 3)
```

Comment: `log(x)` does ln(x) by default. Though your function always seem to return 0. Not sure what you originally intended

Comment: @OganM, well this is supposed to be the likelihood function, Like stands for likelihood. However, the result of multiplication within the Like function results in funny numbers so it's better to take the natural log of Like. But now I'm getting the different problem you just noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply numerical error.

Observe `dnorm(50, sd = 2)` is already getting close to `.Machine$double.xmin`:

```
dnorm(60, sd = 2)
# [1] 7.368231e-197
.Machine$double.xmin
# [1] 2.225074e-308
```

So when you `prod` a bunch of these they'll become (numerically) 0:

```
prod(dnorm(58:60, sd = 2))
# [1] 0
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). If you're trying to plot a normal likelihood, there's no point in going more than 3 standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: They want to take the log of each element and then sum instead of taking the prod, right?

Comment: @Frank if they're doing some maximum likelihood, yes, this is one of the many reasons it's better to deal with log-likelihood! ;-)

Comment: Thank you Michael, is there any way so I could be able to plot the likelihood function regardless of the value of SIGMA?

Comment: @user138773 as Frank emphasizes, the likelihood itself is often not so useful. The log-likelihood share the important topological properties of the likelihood (i.e., same max/min) and doesn't suffer from the same numerical issues.